# Why does the linux kernel raw binary Image has the Windows executable format?

Tags: linux, windows, kernel, portable-executable

According to https://ineclabs.com/image-zimage-uimage-vmlinuz-linux-kernel/

```
Image: The generic Linux kernel binary image file.
```

I have an `ARM64` kernel that I compiled with `make Image` and it's recognized by linux as a Windows executable. At least it gets the windows icon.

On Cutter, I opened and got it recognized by `pe64`

According to [Documentation/arm64/booting.rst](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/ff1176468d368232b684f75e82563369208bc371/Documentation/arm64/booting.rst), this is the kernel header when uncompressed

```
======aarch64 kernel header========
u32 code0;          /* Executable code */
u32 code1;          /* Executable code */
u64 text_offset;        /* Image load offset, little endian */
u64 image_size;     /* Effective Image size, little endian */
u64 flags;          /* kernel flags, little endian */
u64 res2    = 0;        /* reserved */
u64 res3    = 0;        /* reserved */
u64 res4    = 0;        /* reserved */
u32 magic   = 0x644d5241;   /* Magic number, little endian, "ARM\x64" */
u32 res5;           /* reserved (used for PE COFF offset) */
====================================
```

For it to be recognized as PE64, the first 2 bytes should be  `4D 5A`, but I don't see this happening in this kernel header

Answer (score 0):

It's not PE64; it's COFF. Your tools are recognizing any COFF as Windows Executable for some reason. COFF is pretty rare but ARM still uses it in the boot firmware so that's what you get.

Comment: COFF is actually quite common. It's the file format MSVC uses for object files.